# Pandas. How to resample with last day of moth?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I want to resample monthly one time series to daily. So, what I have is:

```py
>> y

2017-01-01    15.034583
2017-02-01    16.984745
2017-03-01    21.982249
2017-04-03    29.043835
dtype: float64


>> y.resample('D').pad()

2017-01-01    15.034583
2017-01-02    15.034583
2017-01-03    15.034583
                ...    
2017-04-01    21.982249
2017-04-02    21.982249
2017-04-03    29.043835
Freq: D, Length: 93, dtype: float64
```

The **y** and resampled **y** both ends with *2017-04-03*. And I want to make resampled **y** ends with *2017-04-30*. How can I do that?

Comment: What would be the values from `2017-04-03` until the end of moth? `29.043835`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new column with the [`MonthEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html) for the last day and resample by day

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

y_last = y.iloc[-1:].copy()
y_last.index = y_last.index + MonthEnd(0)
y = pd.concat([y, y_last])

y.resample('1D').pad()

#               value
# 2017-01-01    15.034583
# 2017-01-02    15.034583
# 2017-01-03    15.034583
# ...   ...
# 2017-04-28    29.043835
# 2017-04-29    29.043835
# 2017-04-30    29.043835
```